# Using Msys2 and MinGW to compile HDF5 but get errors

Tags: c++, mingw, hdf5, msys2

I tried to compile hdf5 with Msys2 and MinGW64.The compile directive is below:

```
./configure --enable-cxx --prefix=/d/xxx/xxx
```

It seems configure does not have any problems.But the make have these problems:

```
H5PL.c:106:43: error: 'RTLD_LAZY' undeclared (first use in this function)
  106 | #define H5PL_OPEN_DLIB(S)       dlopen(S, RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL)
H5PL.c:106:55: error: 'RTLD_LOCAL' undeclared (first use in this function)
  106 | #define H5PL_OPEN_DLIB(S)       dlopen(S, RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL)
```

I found that the main problems are in the H5PL.c.So I checek the source code.And I found the line 106:
[image]

I think the main reason is just like the error message.RTLD_LAZY and RTLD_LOCAL are not decleared.But I do not how to solve this problem.Can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you really need to build that? msys2 has packages for hdf5: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-hdf5?repo=mingw64](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-hdf5?repo=mingw64)

Comment: General rule of thumb: Find where they are declared, often a simple text search like grep will work, and then riddle out from the surrounding context and the build instructions generated by configure why the declarations are not being seen.

Comment: If you're on Windows, why not just use cmake?